# Magento push products with attribute 'product_type' = old to downwards on all catalog pages

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

How can I push the products with attribute 'product_type' = old to downwards on all catalog pages in Magento.

Comment: can you explain more about your question , its hard to understand what you want to try

Comment: Hi Rohit 
I want to reorder the products on catalog page. Those products who are having product attribute ie product_type = old will show at the last of the page.
Suppose if we are showing 200 products on mens catalog page and if only 30 products are marked as product_type = old then those 30 products will be shown at the end of the page.